# LocalStorage doesn't work on fresh install of iOS app

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js, local-storage

I have an iOS application using Phonegap and Backbone and on fresh install of the application through xCode or Testflight, local storage doesn't retain any values that are sent to it.  On each screen, the localstorage values are all null.  However if the app is quit and then restarted, the local storage appears to be working correctly. Even if I install the app again from xCode it is fine, it only doesn't work on a delete of the app and a fresh install.  Any ideas?  This is my local storage line:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("user_name", "emailaddress");
```

Update 1:  The issue actually seems to be backbone related.  In my main home_view.js declaration I call:

```
var View = require('./view');
var template = require('./templates/home'); 
var Posts = require('../models/posts');
var user_name = window.localStorage.getItem("user_name");
```

Then in the render function user_name is null but this seems to fix the issue:

```
    if (user_name == null) {
        location.reload();
    }
```

If I set:

```
    var user_name = window.localStorage.getItem("user_name");
```

in the render function, then user_name is defined for homeview.js but not in any other of the js files.

Comment: can you show us more code, how do you check the values are null?

Comment: When I go to the next page:
  var user_name = window.localStorage.getItem("user_name");
    alert(user_name)
Which gives me null as the result

Comment: are you running the files locally in firefox, with file://?

Comment: I edited the question to maybe give some more clarification.  Viewing the files in local storage actually showed the correct values were there but I can't access them for some reason.  I am running the application in Chrome using brunch.io.